# Using Spy to mock method returned value in service that is under test (unit test)

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I am having trouble using Spy to mock a method returned value inside the service that is under test. I am getting the following error message:

> No transactionManager was specified. Using @Transactional or @Rollback
>   requires a valid configured transaction manager. If you are running in
>   a unit test ensure the test has been properly configured and that you
>   run the test suite not an individual test method.

Here's my sample code:

```
@Transactional 
class MyServie {
    void methodA(String input1, String input2) {
        //Do stuff...
        List<String> stringList = [methodB(input1, input2)]

        //Do stuff...
    }

    String methodB(String input1, String input2, boolean input3 = false) {

        if (input3) {
            return input1
        }

        return input2
    }
}
```

Given the code above, my test class look like this:

```
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def myService = Spy(MyService)

    def "methodA test"() {
        given:
        myService.methodB(_,_,_) >> "TEST"

        when:
        myService.methodA("TEST", "TEST2")
    }
}
```

I've tried adding @Transactional and @Rollback annotation for the test class but still getting the same error message. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your class under test is a DAO. If it has a dependency over a transaction manager you need to use Test Entity manager or something. Please try to post piece of actual code

Answer (score 0):

@AmitPhaltankar Is correct. There was a mongodb transaction in other method within the same class. I solved the issue by adding myService.transactionManager = getTransactionManager() in the setup() and the fixed the issue.

It's actually the same issue as this post: [Grails Spock unit test requires to mock transaction manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831355/grails-spock-unit-test-requires-to-mock-transaction-manager)